# How to add text to different parts of chart made from css, html, and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I'd like to add text to three different parts of the below row chart:

http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/ByjZdp

- A number at the beginning of where the orange begins
- a percentage right before the organge ends
- A number at the end of the entire bar where the gray ends.

Something like this: [image: progress bar chart]

HTML:

```
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="50">
  <div class="progress-bar-state progress">50</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap {
  background: #f80;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  .progress-bar-state {
    background: #ddd;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
// on page load...
    moveProgressBar();
    // on browser resize...
    $(window).resize(function() {
        moveProgressBar();
    });

    // SIGNATURE PROGRESS
    function moveProgressBar() {
      console.log("moveProgressBar");
        var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
        var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
        var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
        var animationLength = 2500;

        // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
        // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
        $('.progress-bar-state').stop().animate({
            left: progressTotal
        }, animationLength);
    }
```

I've tried to just insert the numbers after, but I can't seem to make the numbers relative to the position of 'progress-wrap' or 'progress.' See my attempt here: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/MYKoBq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:before` and `:after` :pseudo-elements.

```js
// on page load...
moveProgressBar();
// on browser resize...
$(window).resize(function() {
  moveProgressBar();
});

// SIGNATURE PROGRESS
function moveProgressBar() {
  console.log("moveProgressBar");
  var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
  var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
  var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
  var animationLength = 2500;

  // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
  // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
  $('.progress-bar-state').stop().animate({
    left: progressTotal
  }, animationLength);
}
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap:before {
  content: '66';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap:after {
  content: '$250,000';
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap {
  background: #f80;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-wrap .progress-bar-state {
  background: #ddd;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Change the below data attribute to play -->
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="50">
  <div class="progress-bar-state progress">50</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but you put some text in the css. Is there a way to put all the number text in the html?

Comment: @Chris - Nope you can't. But you could use JavaScript to change those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As given below, Add/Modify HTML , CSS and JS. It gets your desired output

```
  $('.progress-bar-state').stop().animate({
            left: progressTotal
            width:getProgressWrapWidth - progressTotal
        }, animationLength);
```

HTML

```
<!-- Change the below data attribute to play -->
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="7">
  vd    
  <div class="progress-bar-state progress">8
  <div class="right-content" >RightEnd</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.right-content
{
  float:right;
}
```